# how to aggregate list values by sum of each elem

Tags: python, scripting

I have two lists
people_ids = ['123','456','123','567']
no_of_steps = [15,16,10,15]
Desired Result:
person 123 has taken  25(15+10) steps
 
person 456 has taken 16 steps
person 567 has taken 15 steps.

i was able to achieve it by Pandas Group by function. Can anybody suggest the Python code with out any modules?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Use dictionary to make the simplest solution !!! Do you need solution for that ?

Comment: Yes , Please , that would be so great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any external modules, prints the output as well:

```
people_ids = ['123','456','123','567']
no_of_steps = [15,16,10,15]

people_ids_dict = {}
for index,id_ in enumerate(people_ids):
    if id_ not in people_ids_dict.keys():
        people_ids_dict[id_] = []
    people_ids_dict[id_].append(no_of_steps[index])

# If you're using python 2
#for key,value in people_ids_dict.iteritems():
for key,val in people_ids_dict.items():
    num_steps =  str(sum(val)) + '(' + '+'.join([str(x) for x in val]) + ')' if len(val) > 1 else str(sum(val))
    print('person {0} has taken {1} steps'.format(key,num_steps))
```

Output:

```
person 567 has taken 15 steps
person 456 has taken 16 steps
person 123 has taken 25(15+10) steps
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for j, id in enumerate(people_ids):
    d[id] += no_of_steps[j]

# defaultdict(int, {'123': 25, '456': 16, '567': 15})
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any modules, as requested.

```
# make a dict of the people
d = {k:0 for k in set(people_ids)}

# populate it with the values
for i in xrange(len(no_of_steps)):
    d[people_ids[i]] += no_of_steps[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also `groupby` in python:

```
from itertools import groupby
people_ids = ['123', '456', '123', '567']
no_of_steps = [15, 16, 10, 15]

data = sorted(zip(people_ids, no_of_steps))
for people_id, it in groupby(data, key=lambda _: _[0]):
    print('person {} has taken {} steps'.format(people_id, sum(_[1] for _ in it)))
```

Result:

```
person 123 has taken 25 steps
person 456 has taken 16 steps
person 567 has taken 15 steps
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simplest possible approach:

```
# your data.
people_ids = ['123','456','123','567']
no_of_steps = [15,16,10,15]

# create a dictionary.
d = {}

# loop through every element of people_ids.
for i in range(len(people_ids)):

    # if element is not present id dictionary, then add it to dict and set its value to no_of_steps[i].
    if people_ids[i] not in d:
        d[people_ids[i]] = no_of_steps[i]
   # if value already present then add value of no_of_steps[i] in current value.
    else:
        d[people_ids[i]] += no_of_steps[i]

# for printing in the order of elements present in people_ids.
# loop through every element present in people_ids.
for i in people_ids:
    # if value is present in dict, print it.
    if i in d:
        print('person {} has taken {} steps'.format(i, d[i]))
         # remove the value so that it wont get printed again.
        del d[i]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfect and really appreciate the details description

Comment: Hello Shasha,i did upvote but stack Workflow is saying " people who have reputed less than 15 wil be recorded but will not show in public" , so it will not show. I will keep it in my mind when i get reputed then i will up vote again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
people_ids = ['123','456','123','567']
no_of_steps = [15, 16, 10, 15]

results = {}

for person, steps in zip(people_ids, no_of_steps):
    try:
        results[person] += steps
    except KeyError:
        results[person] = steps
```